# Does every operating system have socket?

Tags: sockets, operating-system

Because every OS I have heard (windows, Linux etc.)has socket.
That make me confused

Is there a standard or something similar to rule developer implement socket in their operating system?

Or just because socket is so useful that every OS implement it?

Comment: An operating system that doesn't offer networking wouldn't need sockets.
Or are you trying to ask why different OS don't use different paradigm for sockets ?

Comment: It's also a part of my confusion. Sorry I can't describe problem very clearly with my poor English ability :(
BTW, if I want to make my operating system offer networking. Do I must implement a "socket"? Or I can build another API with similar function, but not same(different syntax etc.) .
And thank your comment :)

Comment: Solaris at some point had TLI streams (and sockets being officially deprecated). See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1602/tli-33281.html

Comment: Windows for example has always had a complete networking API that doesn't involve sockets. On the other hand, if you want existing and future networking code to port easily to your OS and to other OS then you want to provides a sockets API that adheres closely to relevant sockets standards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many operating systems have an implementation of sockets.  The original sockets API comes from BSD Unix, but  [was standardized](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) in IEEE POSIX.1.

That said, not all operating systems use POSIX as their native networking layer.  There are a number of embedded operating systems where sockets are not the native networking interface.  In some very low memory operating systems the sockets API would be quite challenging to implement.